# I cant access /usr/share/phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I cant access `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` after installing phpmyadmin. When I open the phpmyadmin folder the following error is displayed as an alert box..

You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “phpmyadmin”.

Comment: It's a permission problem. Can you add the output of the following command, please? `stat /usr/share/phpmyadmin/`

Comment: Thats output is as follows:

File: ‘/usr/share/phpmyadmin/’
  Size: 4096       Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 809h/2057d Inode: 542378      Links: 8
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-10-24 15:24:03.176621621 +0530
Modify: 2013-11-08 00:25:30.989454076 +0530
Change: 2013-11-08 00:25:30.989454076 +0530
 Birth: -

Answer (score 0):

As in your comment mentioned you can see that the owner of this folder is root and the permissions are not granted for another user:

```
Access: (0700/drwx------) Uid: ( 0/ root) Gid: ( 0/ root)
```

Normally folders in /usr/share/ have `rwxr-xr-x` (755) permission. You can alter those permissions by the command:

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
```

Then you should have read permission to this folder.